# Where to set the path to webdriver.chrome.driver (Java, Selenium, IntelliJ)?

Tags: java, selenium, path, webdriver

So I'm working with Selenium IDE and it beautifully generated the code for me. But I have an issue with webdriver. This is the code.

```
package org.example;// Generated by Selenium IDE
        import org.junit.Test;
        import org.junit.Before;
        import org.junit.After;
        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
        import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
        import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
        import java.util.*;
public class StorwareTestTest {
        WebDriver driver;
        Map<String, Object> vars;
        JavascriptExecutor js;
        @Before
        public void setUp () {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
        @After
        public void tearDown () {
            driver.quit();
        }
        @Test
        public void storware () {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/wrost/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");

            driver.get("https://storware.eu/");
    (...)
```

So, the compiler is yelling at me that: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;
But I did it. Maybe in the wrong place. What can I do to fix it? I've been working on it for 2 hours, and honestly have no idea. Maybe it's some basic problem. I'm a fresher. And the code is autogenerated by SeleniumIDE, so it probably does a bunch of stuff I don't even know about. Maybe it shouldn't be under @Test annotation. But then where?  (When I was writing basic programs using Selenium with Java everything worked. But I also want to know how SeleniumIDE works, and that's where the problems started).
Thanks for Your help!

Comment: Place the `System.setProperty` line in the `setUp` method, before instantiating the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally the `System.setProperty()` line should be mentioned before you initialize the *ChromeDriver* driven [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browsing context.

Effectively your code block will be:

```
@Before
public void setUp () {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/wrost/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    vars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```